# jQuery issue and wp_enqueue_script

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Actually i have one theme with enqueue for insert jquery code and reference for the core and also jquery iu

Bus happend things that i don´t understad, actually as i tell until i need insert code for create slide of images , simple slide with popular plugin which works perfect in single pages

For this i create simple shortcode and show images and this move into slide

When i create the shortcode this show the images but no move , i see if the code of plugin load in the DOM and i see the perfect reference and the reference also to the core of jquery inside the head in the theme and when load the page

I see one time and other time and the slider no works , finally i put the reference remote code of jquery inside the content ofr shortcode and finally the scrip of slider works  but all jquery code of the rest of my blog , never more works and in the dom i see 2 calls to load jquery core

I don´t understand if i see in the head  - in the DOM - the reference to general core of jquery , why no works the scripts all , because in the DOM i see this jquery core and all scripts mus works perfectly , if the core load , but also works if core of jquery it´s until inside the shortcode

How it´s possible

Sorry i hope understand all regards

For example this , only works the codes about this plugin if until put the call to remote core of jquery and if no , no load nothing and this core code really load in the head .....

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-cycle',  TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', array('jquery'), null );
```

For no get problems i create this but continue the problems :

```
function fix_noconflict() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery' , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'fix_noconflict' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practise while developing a Wordpress theme is to **always use** the jquery included in WP. So deregister it and use a cdn hosted version should be avoided.

This is a required practise, e.g. to include themes in wordpress repository and also some famous themes marketplaces (like themeforest) at this time do not accept themes that use a cdn hosted version of jQuery.

After that, your code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-cycle',  TEMPLATE_PATH . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', array('jquery'), null );
```

is a bit wrong, because `TEMPLATE_PATH` return the *path* of the theme, but `wp_enqueue_script` need the *url*. Another problem is that `wp_enqueue_script` should be called using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook (`admin_enqueue_scripts` for backed). See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Notes)

So you should replace previous code with:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'enqueue_my_scripts');

function enqueue_my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-cycle',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', array('jquery'), null );
}
```

Note how I've used the `add_action` function to hook into `wp_enqueue_script` action and how inside the function I've used `get_template_directory_uri` function to retrieve the *url* of the theme root folder.

See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) docs for `add_action`, [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) docs for the `wp_enqueue_script` hook and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) docs for `get_template_directory_uri`.

From codex, in the `wp_enqueue_script` docs page ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)) you can read

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict()
>   mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent
>   compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress
>   can link.

So every script that use jquery in wordpress must be wrapped in one of the [noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). For example, if you want ot use this code (example taken from jquery cycle docs):

```
$('#shuffle').cycle({ 
    fx:     'shuffle', 
    easing: 'easeOutBack', 
    delay:  -4000 
})
```

you need to wrap it with noConflict wrapper, so it should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#shuffle').cycle({ 
        fx:     'shuffle', 
        easing: 'easeOutBack', 
        delay:  -4000 
    })

});
```

Probably in your code you have used, the `$` jQuery shortcut *directly* and for this reason it doesn't work.